# Function to convert alphanumeric string to numeric string in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have created a below function in oracle to convert an alpha numeric string to a numeric string. But i am not sure that this is a effective solution.

```
create or replace FUNCTION TEXT_TO_NUMERIC(
    TEXT_VALUE VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  NUMBER_VALUE VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( TRANSLATE( TRANSLATE( TEXT_VALUE, 'abcdefghij', '0123456789'), 'ABCDEFGHIJ', '0123456789') , 'k', '10'), 'l', '11'), 'm', '12'), 'n', '13'), 'o', '14'), 'p', '15'), 'q', '16'), 'r', '17'), 's', '18'), 't', '19'), 'u', '20'), 'v', '21'), 'w', '22'), 'x', '23'), 'y', '24'), 'z', '25') , 'K', '10'), 'L', '11'), 'M', '12'), 'N', '13'), 'O', '14'), 'P', '15'), 'Q', '16'), 'R', '17'), 'S', '18'), 'T', '19'), 'U', '20'), 'V', '21'), 'W', '22'), 'X', '23'), 'Y', '24'), 'Z', '25')
  INTO NUMBER_VALUE
  FROM DUAL;
  RETURN(NUMBER_VALUE);
END;
```

> ***Below is my sample output, which is as per my expectation.***

[image: sampe output]

I tried to use CAST function but it is not effective for all aphabets.

[image: cast in oracle]

***Is there any alternate way to achieve my goal in oracle?***

Comment: You can at least eliminate one of the `TRANSLATE` calls by replacing `TRANSLATE( TRANSLATE(TEXT_VALUE, 'abcdefghij', '0123456789'), 'ABCDEFGHIJ', '0123456789')` with `TRANSLATE(TEXT_VALUE, 'abcdefghijABCDEFGHIJ', '01234567890123456789')`

Comment: So, what's the assignment - given any string, return that string with 'a' and 'A' replaced by '0', ... ,  'z' and 'Z' replaced by '25', and all other characters left unchanged?

Comment: My requirement is , If I give a alphanumeric string, it should convert into a numeric string, but it should be unique. The same value should not be populated for any other alphanumeric combination.

Comment: I tried to use ORA_HASH function as well, but it is populating non unique values. I am getting same numeric values for multiple combination of alphanumeric strings.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you want to use this for. Even if individual characters are mapped to distinct values, the strings 'aw' and 'ma' will both be mapped to the string '121' ('aw' because 'a' maps to '1' and 'w' maps to '21', and 'ma' because 'm' maps to '12' and 'a' maps to '1').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do what you're looking for without all the repeated `REPLACE` calls:

```
create or replace FUNCTION TEXT_TO_NUMERIC(
    TEXT_VALUE VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  NUMBER_VALUE VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  WITH cteChars AS (SELECT SUBSTR(LOWER(TEXT_VALUE), LEVEL, 1) AS TEXT_CHAR
                      FROM DUAL
                      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(TEXT_VALUE)),
       cteNums AS (SELECT CASE
                            WHEN TEXT_CHAR BETWEEN 'a' AND 'z' THEN TO_CHAR(ASCII(TEXT_CHAR)-97)
                            ELSE TEXT_CHAR
                          END AS NUM,
                          ROWNUM AS RN
                     FROM cteChars)
  SELECT LISTAGG(NUM, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rn) AS NUM_STRING
    INTO NUMBER_VALUE
    FROM cteNums;

  RETURN NUMBER_VALUE;
END;
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a2d3853368d9e22d250e768373a16715)

Comment: This solution works. But when I try to use this functon for a table with huge data, I  am having performance issues. Is there any alternate way to generate unique numeric value for  unique alphanumeric strings?

Comment: @aravind - **What do you need this for?** There are many ways to convert distinct letters to distinct numbers. For example (and better than your approach, since each letter is replaced by exactly two digits), you can easily replace each letter with its ASCII code. You can pass the input string to `upper()`, first, if lower-case and upper-case letters must get the same code.

Comment: @mathguy  - I need this comparing columns from from two different tables (in java), I am fetching the records and comparing the values in java, in java code integer comparison is much faster then String comparison. So, I want convert all the unique alphanumeric values as unique numeric values in SQL itslef so i do not need to do any conversion in Java.

Comment: @aravind - you are going about this the wrong way. Why don't you compare the columns in the database, not in java? Oracle has some really cool tools (not to mention highly optimized, especially compared to something like java) for comparing text values.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do this. I use the `lateral` clause, available since Oracle 12.1, to make the query more efficient (assuming you must encrypt more than just one string at a time). If your version is <= 11.2, then this can be rewritten; and let this be a good example for you as to why you should *always* include your Oracle version.

I collected a few test strings at the top, in the `WITH` clause (which is not part of the solution - remove it and use your actual table and column names in the main query).

```
with
  input_strings (str) as (
    select 'abc, de,xy  003 UFO' from dual union all
    select null                  from dual union all
    select '12345 bcdef BCDEF'   from dual
  )
select str, new_str
from   input_strings,
       lateral ( select  listagg(case when upper(ch) between 'A' and 'Z'
                                      then to_char(ascii(upper(ch)) - ascii('A'))
                                      else ch
                                 end  ) within group (order by ord) as new_str
                 from    ( select  substr(str, level, 1) as ch, level as ord
                           from    dual
                           connect by level <= length(str)
                         )
               )
;

column new_str format a30

STR                  NEW_STR                       
-------------------- ------------------------------
abc, de,xy  003 UFO  012, 34,2324  003 20514       

12345 bcdef BCDEF    12345 12345 12345
```